# [Boost::ext].SML: Access SM and dependencies in an action

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, state-machine, boost-extension

I'm using SML (https://boost-ext.github.io/sml/) v.1.1.3 and I need to access the injected dependencies and the state machine in actions.
According to the following commit this should already work: https://github.com/boost-ext/sml/commit/e6d0685993a8a0160dde1610d7f8be4f811c89d0
This commit was the result of this issue:
https://github.com/boost-ext/sml/issues/94

With the subsequent example, where I try to access the dependencies and sm in action2, I get a compile error:

```
sml.hpp:1853:18: note:   cannot convert ‘deps’ (type ‘boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::aux::pool<int, {anonymous}::actions_guards&, {anonymous}::actions_guards>’) to type ‘int&’  1853 |     return object(event, sm, deps, subs);
```

Example:

```
#include <boost/sml.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

namespace sml = boost::sml;

namespace {
 
struct e1 {};
struct e2 {};
struct e3 {};

auto action2 = [](const auto& event, auto& sm, int& i, std::string& str) {
    assert(42 == i);
    std::cout << "action2" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sm.n: " << sm.n << std::endl;
};

struct actions_guards {
    using self = actions_guards;

    int n = 10;

    auto operator()() {
        using namespace sml;

        auto action1 = [](auto e) { std::cout << "action1: " << typeid(e).name() << std::endl; };

        auto guard1 = [](int i) {
            assert(42 == i);
            std::cout << "guard2" << std::endl;
            return false;
        };

        return make_transition_table(
            //  Start           Event             Guard                         Action                        Next
            //+-------------+-------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
                *"idle"_s   +   event<e1>       [ guard1 ]                  /   action1                     = "s1"_s,
                "s1"_s      +   event<e2>       [ &self::guard2 ]           /   action2                     = "s2"_s,
                "s2"_s      +   event<e3>                                                                   = X
        );
    }

    bool guard2(int i) const noexcept {
        assert(42 == i);
        std::cout << "guard3" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

}  // namespace

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    actions_guards ag{};
    std::string strDep( "127.0.0.1" );
    int intDep = 42;
    sml::sm<actions_guards> sm{ag, intDep, strDep};
    sm.process_event(e1{});
    sm.process_event(e2{});
    sm.process_event(e3{});

    assert(sm.is(sml::X));

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
...
sml.hpp:1340:10:   required from ‘bool boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::back::sm_impl< <template-parameter-1-1> >::process_event(const TEvent&, TDeps&, TSubs&) [with TEvent = {anonymous}::e2; TDeps = boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::aux::pool<int, {anonymous}::actions_guards&, {anonymous}::actions_guards>; TSubs = boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::aux::pool<boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::back::sm_impl<boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::back::sm_policy<{anonymous}::actions_guards> > >; TSM = boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::back::sm_policy<{anonymous}::actions_guards>]’
/usr/local/oecore-x86_64_tux_dunfell/sysroots/armv5te-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/boost/sml.hpp:1660:81:   required from ‘bool boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::back::sm< <template-parameter-1-1> >::process_event(const TEvent&) [with TEvent = {anonymous}::e2; typename boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::aux::enable_if<boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::aux::integral_constant<bool, __is_base_of(TEvent, boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::back::sm::events_ids)>::value, int>::type <anonymous> = 0; TSM = boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::back::sm_policy<{anonymous}::actions_guards>]’
main.cpp:86:23:   required from here
/usr/local/oecore-x86_64_tux_dunfell/sysroots/armv5te-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/boost/sml.hpp:1853:18: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::aux::zero_wrapper<{anonymous}::<lambda(const auto:3&, auto:4&, int&, std::string&)>, void>) (const {anonymous}::e2&, boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::back::sm_impl<boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::back::sm_policy<{anonymous}::actions_guards> >&, boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::aux::pool<int, {anonymous}::actions_guards&, {anonymous}::actions_guards>&, boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::aux::pool<boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::back::sm_impl<boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::back::sm_policy<{anonymous}::actions_guards> > >&)’
 1853 |     return object(event, sm, deps, subs);
      |            ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:37:16: note: candidate: ‘template<class auto:3, class auto:4> {anonymous}::<lambda(const auto:3&, auto:4&, int&, std::string&)>’
   37 | auto action2 = [](const auto& event, auto& sm, int& i, std::string& str) {
      |                ^
main.cpp:37:16: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from main.cpp:20:
/usr/local/oecore-x86_64_tux_dunfell/sysroots/armv5te-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/boost/sml.hpp:1853:18: note:   cannot convert ‘deps’ (type ‘boost::ext::sml::v1_1_3::aux::pool<int, {anonymous}::actions_guards&, {anonymous}::actions_guards>’) to type ‘int&’
 1853 |     return object(event, sm, deps, subs);
      |            ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from the author of SML at the end of issue [#399](https://github.com/boost-ext/sml/issues/399):

The implementation of this feature has changed to avoid recursive calls and be compliant with the UML-2.5

Example

```
s1 + event<e1> / [](sml::back::process<e2, e3> processEvent) -> void {
            processEvent(e2{});
            processEvent(e3{});
          }
```

The process_queue has to be specified when defining sm

```
sml::sm<c, sml::process_queue<std::queue>> sm{};
```

[Full example](https://github.com/boost-ext/sml/blob/master/test/ft/actions_process.cpp#L171)

Here the adapted example from my actual question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <queue>
#include <boost/sml.hpp>

namespace sml = boost::sml;

struct e1 {};
struct e2 {};
struct e3 {};

struct my_dep {
    int val = 0;
};

auto action = [](sml::back::process<e2, e3> processEvent, my_dep& dep) {
    if (dep.val == 0) {
        processEvent(e2{});
        ++dep.val;
    }
    else
        processEvent(e3{});
};

struct table {
    auto operator()() const noexcept {
        using namespace sml;
        return make_transition_table(
            *"s1"_s + event<e1> / action = "s3"_s
            ,"s1"_s + event<e2> = "s2"_s
            ,"s3"_s + event<e2> = "s4"_s
            ,"s3"_s + event<e3> = "s5"_s
            ,"s4"_s + event<e1> = "s1"_s
        );
    }
};

int main() {
    using namespace sml;
    my_dep md;
    sm<table, sml::process_queue<std::queue>> sm{md};

    sm.process_event(e1{});
    assert(sm.is("s4"_s));

    sm.process_event(e1{});
    assert(sm.is("s1"_s));

    sm.process_event(e1{});
    assert(sm.is("s5"_s));
}
```